# What kept Egyptian Obelisks upright?

Tags: ancient-egypt, standing-stones

I'm NOT asking about how an Obelisk was erected, but what keeps it upright once it's in place?

The few sources I can find (and the modern youtube re-enactments) all seem to imply that the obelisk has a perfectly flat base and it's balanced on a perfectly flat pedestal or plinth.

To me this seems akin to attempting to balance a pencil on a table - it may stay balanced for a few moments, but not for long.

The modern solution would be a metal peg in the pedestal engaging with a hole in the base of the obelisk - but the ancient Egyptians had little (or no) access to anything harder than copper.

Ancient standing stones in northern Europe were held upright by burying about a third of the length of stone in the ground, but these stones were a lot shorter (10m for the Kerloas Menhir in France) and many fell over anyway.

So what keeps the Egyptians ones upright? don't they ever experience strong winds or earthquakes?

Comment: This seems to be more of a physics question than a historic one. The tapering shape keeps the centre of gravity low and the wider base makes it harder to topple. Move it enough and it will fall over. If it remains intact, it gets put back upright. If it falls apart, it gets used as material for other buildings/walls/roads/etc.

Comment: @SteveBird - I'd imagine the great weight plays a part as well. Agree, this seems like its asking a question of physics and/or engineering.

Comment: It seems to me the main difference to northern Europe standing stones is that those were buried into earth or gravel with the potential to give way, while the Egyptian Obelisks have a planar base that stands on a equally planar and wide stone foundation (maybe with a accurately hewn stone pedestal inbetween). As long as the base can be considered approximately immovable, you would have to raise the center of gravity of, let's say the Luxor Obelisk (250t, height 23.5m, base ca. 2.5m?), by around 60-70cm before it topples over.

Comment: Also, if you look closely at [this picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Luxor_Tempel_09.jpg) of the original base, it seems it was secured against sideway movement with a wooden peg (same as you find as connectors between drums of columns in classical antiquity).

Comment: As an Engineer, this is not a basic physics question. If I had to build a stone obelisk, I could think of several ways of supporting it and some of them may work or not work. Asking how did the ancients support obelisks is a perfectly legit historical question - on history of technology, if you want.

Comment: @ccprog: yeah, a wood peg would work for a while. In fact for quite a while longer in Egypt than in Europe, due to lower year-long humidity. Some Egyptian pyramids still have their ancient wooden beams in place! I'm not sure if there are earthquake differences between Europe and Egypt. Surely some areas of Europe have more quakes though. Italy etc. Egypt quake risk map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earthquakes_in_Egypt#/media/File:Turkey_seismic_hazard.jpg